# How to plot bars in log scale y axis for data close to 0 in ggpot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that range from 0.00008 to ~2400, which are measurements between different methods.

I've tried this bar char in OpenOffice and it looks fine for my purposes:

[image: Log-scale bar chart]

Now I'm trying to do the same in ggplot2 but having problems with the small numbers ending up below the origin:

[image: Same plot with ggplot2]

Now I guess that this because the origin is at 1 but in the end I'd like to have the result of the first figure.

Is there some way to do this by changing the origin, limiting the displayed data or using another geom like `geom_rect`? Open to visualization suggestions other than bar charts as well.

EDIT: Using `geom_point` we end up with a rather "empty" graph which is what I'm trying to avoid:

[image]

Comment: `1e-02` is a positive number. The `-2` is the power.

Comment: @anotherfred Corrected, what I meant it's that it's below the origin.

Comment: Don't use a log axis with bar charts, bars are interpreted by their length/size and using a log axis visually distorts that. Use another geom instead, maybe `geom_point()` or `geom_pointrange() to show uncertanty`.

Comment: @Nate I agree that bars are a bad visualization here. However, when using geom_point the graph ends up looking rather "empty" so I'm wondering if there's a better way to visualize.  I'll add it to the question.

Comment: You're right, with only one value per category it might look empty and all you can really do is adjust the size, or make a plot with only differences/percent changes if you are really comparing the difference in methods. But if you actually have more samples, then I would show all of the sample values with points and use `geom_crossbar()` to show the group mean +/- some error measurement. Also I like using `+ annotation_logticks(side = 'l')` with log scales, bc it adds log tick marks on y and really helps readers appreciate the non-linearity.

Comment: @Nate agreed on the tickmarcks. However using facets adds them to every plot making it very ugly. SO says no easy solution exists. I'll have to keep iterating on this.

Comment: Use bigger points in a smaller graph. Display uncertainty whenever possible. Never use bars in a log plot, the OpenOffice plot does _not_ look ok, in my opinion. People will think a bar is twice as large as another bar and that means the value is twice as high, but that is not at all the case in a log plot! Not much else to do!